# Creating nested array in JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table structure like this:

[image: table structure]

I want to create a JSON out of this table in this form:

```
{
    "EntityId": 100000,
    "Years": [
        {
            "Year": 2008,
            "Monthly": [
                {
                    "Month": 1,
                    "Count1": 49,
                    "Count2": 2
                },
                {
                    "Month": 2,
                    "Count1": 45,
                    "Count2": 1
                },
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        },
        {
            "Year": 2009,
            "Monthly": [
                {
                    "Month": 1,
                    "Count1": 36,
                    "Count2": 1
                },
                {
                    "Month": 2,
                    "Count1": 33,
                    "Count2": 0
                },
                .
                .
                .

            ]
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

This table will always be queried for a single `EntityId`.

I am not able to nest my arrays also the years are repeating (the number of times the year gets repeated is the number of months inside that year, so if I have 12 months of data for the year 2008 then this year's data gets repeated 12 times) when I try the below query:

```
select f.EntityId, 
    (
        select TOP 1 [year] as [year],
        (
            select [month] as [month],
                [count1] as [count1],
                [count2] as [count2],
            from someTable m            
            where m.EntityId = f.EntityId and m.Year = y.Year 
            for json path
        ) as [months]
        from someTable y
        where y.EntityId = f.EntityId and y.Year = f.Year       
        for json path
    ) AS years
from someTable f 
where f.EntityId = f.EntityId   
for json path
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    SELECT
        OuterData1,
        OuterData2,
        ,(SELECT InnerData1, InnerData2
            FROM Table2
            FOR JSON PATH) InnerJson
        OuterData3,
        OuterData4
    FROM Table1
    FOR JSON PATH
```